# FWA for CSS based sites

Tags: language-agnostic

Does anyone have a favorite style site that posts the latest and greatest sites constructed with CSS + HTML + JS?  I'm thinking of something like thefwa.com but not for all flash microsites.  Trying to find the definitive portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.csszengarden.com/ sorta started it all, and http://www.cssbeauty.com/ is keeping it going.